# Как задать несколько list() для аргумента функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример:

```
def test(arg=['asd', 'qwe'])
```

Чтобы при вводе аргумент принимал только те значения, которые я передал изначально в функции.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Сделать так, чтобы аргумент `arg` принимал только переданные значения

Comment: Понятнее не стало

Comment: Вызываю функцию `test()` с аргументом `zxc`, этого аргумента нет в списке заданных, значит должно выдать ошибку. Вызываю функцию `test()` с аргументом `asd`, этот аргумент есть в списке, значит код выполнится. Не знаю как объяснить понятнее, извиняюсь заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test(x):
    if not x in ['asd', 'qwe']:
        return
    #здесь идет ваш код
```